# Has /bin/sh always been a symbolic link?

Tags: linux, shell, history

In Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link that points to `/bin/dash`.

Has there been a Unix or Unix-like operating system where `/bin/sh` was an actual shell and not a symbolic link that points to a shell?

Comment: Yes, it used to be the Bourne Shell, and more ancient than bash. dash is a cut-down static linked version. see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-binbash-vs-bindash-vs-binshshell/

Comment: Minor nit-pick — `dash` isn’t usually statically linked, it just doesn’t need much in the way of libraries.

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu, it was not *always* a symlink to `dash`.  This occurred with the release of Ubuntu 6.10.  An extensive document explaining the rationale for the change can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).

From that document:

> The major reason to switch the default shell was efficiency. bash is
>   an excellent full-featured shell appropriate for interactive use;
>   indeed, it is still the default login shell. However, it is rather
>   large and slow to start up and operate by comparison with dash. A
>   large number of shell instances are started as part of the Ubuntu boot
>   process. Rather than change each of them individually to run
>   explicitly under /bin/dash, a change which would require significant
>   ongoing maintenance and which would be liable to regress if not paid
>   close attention, the Ubuntu core development team felt that it was
>   best simply to change the default shell. The boot speed improvements
>   in Ubuntu 6.10 were often incorrectly attributed to Upstart, which is
>   a fine platform for future development of the init system but in
>   Ubuntu 6.10 was primarily running in System V compatibility mode with
>   only small behavioural changes. These improvements were in fact
>   largely due to the changed /bin/sh.

Answer (score 5):

`sh` cannot have always been a symbolic link, as symbolic links were only introduced in 4.2 BSD (1977) and the older [Sixth Edition of Unix](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6) has

```
$ tar tvzf v6root.tar.gz  | grep 5888
-rwxrwxr-x  0 3      3        5888 May 13  1975 ./bin/sh
$
```

You can see BSDs today that do not have `/bin/sh` as a symbolic link.  For examples:

- On OpenBSD it is a hard link to the Korn shell (OpenBSD's variant of `pdksh`):

  ```
  $ ls -il /bin/{,k,rk}sh
  26004 -r-xr-xr-x  3 root  bin  469976 Feb 26  2016 /bin/ksh
  26004 -r-xr-xr-x  3 root  bin  469976 Feb 26  2016 /bin/rksh
  26004 -r-xr-xr-x  3 root  bin  469976 Feb 26  2016 /bin/sh
  $
  ```
- On FreeBSD it is a descendant of the Almquist shell:

  ```
  % ls -il /bin/sh
  561595 -r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  143432 Jan  7  2017 /bin/sh
  %
  ```

Comment: I can push back the dates a little earlier. The second editions's  [login](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V2/cmd/login.s) program called `/bin/sh`. Symlinks were in BSD at least as far back as [4.1c](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.1cBSD/usr/man/man2/symlink.2)